# Getting error message from WebMethod while keeping Web.Config secure

Tags: c#, security, jquery, web-config

I have a page that's doing jQuery Ajax calls to a WebMethod in one of my ASPX pages. In some cases, my WebMethod is throwing an exception with an error message. This error message is really important for the UI, because it tells what to say to the user, so he can fix his form.

This is working fine in development environnement. But, in my production Web.Config, I need to keep customErrors set to "On", so I wont show important information. Moreover, my IIS is overriding HTTP 500 errors too.

I tried the WebServices from ASMX, and it was working perfectly. IIS wasn't overriding my HTTP 500, and customErrors was not hiding the message sent by the WebService. But migrating all my ASPX's WebMethods to ASMX files is not possible for now.

I'm looking for a guideline. How my UI can gets my WebMethod's errors, while keeping my Web.Config safe for production?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **never** show a yellow screen of death to a user.

Instead, consider implementing a Response object, contaning a boolean Success, an ErrorMessage (string) and the actual result data if needed.

You can then use a JavaScript callback and check if the call succeded. If it did not, just alert() the error message.

Comment: That's what I finally did. But I don't like the solution because the serveur is always responding with Http 200, even if there is an error. Do you know a way to handle my exceptions using the http standard?

Comment: 500 is not the good way to handle it using the HTTP standard, since this means internal error. 
If you want to handle it with the HTTP standard, use the specification per say. If the error is coming from the client (ie: you send data using jQuery and this data is not valid), then use 4XX status codes.

Starting from that, you can use the failed callback from jQuery AJAX calls (see [this](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#example-3) for an example). Using the failed callback allows you to show a message, without having to show an Error screen

Comment: Still, even though this is a good approach, it is not that important when using WebMethods since they are not very RESTful. You should maybe check ASP.NET Web APIs to see if they are more adapated to your need (asmx/page methods are getting old)

Comment: Thank you for those details!